# Error: Data must be an object, value must be an array - Posting Expo push token from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, expo

I have a Rails app, and through sidekiq, I want to send a post request to Expo, in order to handle an in-app notification. The app's API is built using Node.JS, and the push token successfully executes with this code:

```
                    axios({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send",
                        data: {
                            to: result.expo_push_token,
                            title: `${data.user.first_name}`,
                            sound: "default",
                            body: shortMessage,
                            data: {
                                status: "ok",
                                body: shortMessage,
                                title: `${data.user.first_name}`,
                                msgUser: data.user,
                                convoId: data.room,
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

In the Rails app, everything was working fine until I wanted to pass a data object to the app. Here's what worked:

```
        push_tokens = PushToken.where(user_id: other_user)

        push_tokens.each do |token|
            params = ({

              to: token.expo_push_token,
              title: user.first_name,
              sound: "default",
              body: msg.body
            })


            puts params
            puts params.class

            x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send'), params)
            puts x.body
```

And then when I add the data object, it gives the error: `{'errors':[{"code":'API_ERROR','message':'child \'data\' fails because [\'data\' must be an object], \'value\' must be an array.'}]}`

```
        push_tokens.each do |token|
            params = ({

              to: token.expo_push_token,
              title: user.first_name,
              sound: "default",
              body: msg.body,
              data: {
                status: "ok",
                msgUser: {
                  id: user.id,
                  avatar_file_name: user.avatar_file_name,
                  first_name: user.first_name,
                },
                convoId: msg.convo_id,
                body: msg.body,
                title: user.first_name,
              },
            })


            puts params
            puts params.class

            x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send'), params)
            puts x.body
```

Originally, I was passing an ActiveRecord to data to `msgUser: user`, and thought maybe that was the issue, but it made no difference when I created an array myself by doing: `msgUser: {id: user.id, avatar_file_name: user.avatar_file_name, first_name: user.first_name,},`. A simple `data: {status: 'ok'}` doesn't work either.

I've also tried `data: [status: 'ok']` with `[ ]`, `params.to_json`, and `params.as_json`, but I get the same error.

How can I successfully send this `data` object through this Rails post request to an expo push token?

Comment: This works for me `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send -d '{
 "to":"ExponentPushToken[PUSHTOKEN]",
 "title":"the title",
 "body":"this is working like a charm!",
 "data":{"keyA":"my_value_1", "keyB":"my_value_2"}
}`. Take a look [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-python/blob/9e93233c36c907079e21107e73f3b9258f105103/exponent_server_sdk/__init__.py#L76)

Comment: I'm unsure what you're suggesting, and what you're linking to. It looks like a Python SDK? I already said a way how it's working in a different language, in the first example - I'm wanting to know why the Rails way is not working, and the correct way to write the data object above.

Comment: The reason, I feel it could not be working is, since your keys are symbolized and in my code I'm using the keys and values in the `dict` as **string**. Also, the SDK belongs to Python, but just a reference to the **error**.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I put quotes around everything, and it didn't make a difference. I want to emphasize that only when I added the data object, did the error occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working code in my application, can you try this out

In your controller, where you're triggering your Job do the following

```
# Controller
push_tokens.each do |token|
  WorkerClass.perform_async(token, @user)
end

# Worker file
class WorkerClass
  def perform(token, user)
    uri = URI.parse("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send")
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      request.body = {"to"=>token.expo_push_token, "title"=>user.first_name, "body"=>"your_message", "data"=>{"status"=>"ok"}}.to_json
      response = http.request(request)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - that works! Still unsure why adding the data object created an error, but before that the notification worked fine. Also - I didn't need the quotes around all the keys, it's actually how you configured the call that I believe fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your help!